# Pass ThreadLocal class to another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using ThreadLocal within my Java program inorder to get and set certain data members through out the thread.

I have a class with the following content

```
public class ThreadLocalManager {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> accountUsername = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> accountPassword = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    public static final ThreadLocal<Long> accountId = new ThreadLocal<Long>();
    .....................
    .....................
    .....................

}
```

I have been using this with no problems in my multi threaded application. Now each thread will be creating another thread and I want ThreadLocalManager to be passed to the new thread that was created. How would this be done?

Comment: There's no point in passing a `ThreadLocal` to another thread. You'll need to pass the actual values.

Comment: Maybe you need InheritableThreadLocal? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html

Comment: @tsolakp Cool, first time I've come across that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I modified my example code from my original suggestion (below) to use `InheritableThreadLocal` and I find it to be much simpler so adding the updated code.

Here is the updated ThreadLocalManager:

```
package inheritableThreadLocal;

public class ThreadLocalManager {
    public static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> accountUsername = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>();
    public static final InheritableThreadLocal<String> accountPassword = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>();
    public static final InheritableThreadLocal<Long> accountId = new InheritableThreadLocal<Long>();
}
```

I also updated `Runner` (see original below) but now its only purpose is to print the values of the variables:

```
package inheritableThreadLocal;

public class Runner implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside Runner's run");
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());
    }

}
```

Finally the updated class containing the main method:

```
package inheritableThreadLocal;

public class ThreadLocalMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("At start of main");
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ThreadLocalManager.accountId.set(new Long(12345));
                ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.set("user1");
                ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.set("pass1");

                System.out.println("In t1 run");
                System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
                System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
                System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());

                Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runner());
                t2.start();
            }

        });
        t1.start();
    }

}
```

**Original Suggestion:**

So you could create your new `Thread` objects by using `Runnable` objects. If you do that you can create custom objects that implement `Runnable` and can hold the values of the `ThreadLocal` variables until the new `Thread` is started. Once the new `Thread` starts (i.e. `run` method is called) these custom `Runnable` objects set the `ThreadLocal` variables.

Here's a class with a main I created for this:

```
package threadLocal;

public class ThreadLocalMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("At start of main");
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ThreadLocalManager.accountId.set(new Long(12345));
                ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.set("user1");
                ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.set("pass1");

                System.out.println("In t1 run");
                System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
                System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
                System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());

                Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runner(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get(),
                        ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get(),
                        ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get()));
                t2.start();
            }

        });
        t1.start();
    }

}
```

For completeness here's the ThreadLocalManager I used:

```
package threadLocal;

public class ThreadLocalManager {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> accountUsername = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> accountPassword = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    public static final ThreadLocal<Long> accountId = new ThreadLocal<Long>();
}
```

Lastly, here is the custom `Runnable` I created:

```
package threadLocal;

public class Runner implements Runnable{

    private String userName, password;
    private long acctId;

    public Runner(String user, String pword, long accountId){
        System.out.println("In Runner constructor");
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());

        userName = user;
        password = pword;
        acctId = accountId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside Runner's run");
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());

        ThreadLocalManager.accountId.set(acctId);
        ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.set(userName);
        ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.set(password);

        System.out.println("Inside Runner's run - after setting");
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountId.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountUsername.get());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalManager.accountPassword.get());
    }

}
```

This code passes the values of the `ThreadLocal` variables into the `Runner` instance and then the `Runner` instance is used to create a new `Thread` (which as you will see if you run the code has no values for the `ThreadLocal` variables at first). Then the `Runner` sets the `ThreadLocal` variables and as you can see from the console output they match what t1 had.

Hope this helps!